# Use Regular Expressions to find URLs without certain word patterns

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a Regular Expression that can match URLs that don't have a certain pattern. The URLs I am trying to filter out shouldn't have an ID in them, which is 40 Hex uppercase characters.

For example, If I have the following URLs:

`/dev/api/appid/A1B2C3D4E5A1B2C3D4E5A1B2C3D4E5A1B2C3D4E5/users`

`/dev/api/apps/list`

`/dev/api/help/apps/applicationname/apple/osversion/list/`

(urls are made up, but the idea is that there are some endpoints with 40-length IDs, and some endpoints that don't, and some endpoints that are really long in total characters)

I want to make sure that the regular expression is only able to match the last 2 URLs, and not the first one.

I wrote the following regex,

`\S+(?:[0-9A-F]{40})\S+`

and it matches endpoints that do have the long ID in them, but skips over the ones that should be filtered. If I try to negate the regex,

`\S+(?![0-9A-F]{40})\S+`

It matches all endpoints, because some URLs have lengths that are greater than what the ID should be (40 characters).

How can I use a regular expression to filter out exactly the URLs I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`^(?!.*\/[0-9A-F]{40}\/).*$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R7a4UD/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string/url
- `(?!.*\/[0-9A-F]{40}\/)` - [Negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for the presence of a `/` followed by exactly 40 HEX characters followed by `/` somewhere in the string. Since, it is a negative lookahead, any string/url containing this pattern will not be matched.
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, the explanation helps a lot. Negative lookahead has been the hardest things for me to understand so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?![A-F0-9]{40}).)*$
```

Uses a negative lookahead to match any line that doesn't have 40 hex digits in a row. [Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/R25V0g/2)

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. I slightly changed it to

`^((?![A-F0-9]{40})\S)*$`

because there shouldn't be any spaces.